# Пишет что не заполнены все поля

Tags: php, mysql

У меня проблема с кодом, когда нажимаю кнопку **добавить тарифный план** -  пишет, что не все поля заполнены

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['addplan'])){                                               
        if (empty($name) || empty($description) || empty($price) || empty($mbt) || empty($conc) || empty($length) || empty($unit) || empty($vip)){
            echo $design->alert('danger', 'Error', 'Пожалуйста, заполните все поля!');
        } else {
            $SQLinsert = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO `plans` VALUES(NULL, :name, :mbt, :unit, :length, :price, :conc, :description, :vip)");
            $SQLinsert->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':mbt' => $mbt, ':unit' => $unit, ':length' => $length, ':price' => $price, ':conc' => $conc, ':description' => $description, ':vip' => $vip));
            echo $design->alert('success', 'Success', 'Тарифный план успешно создан!');

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы, сэр, в виде жеста доброй воли сдвинуть Ваш код влево до упора?

Comment: Возможно у вас действительно не все поля заполнены?)

Comment: А что должно написать?

Comment: Может стоит проверять данные в `$_POST` ?

Answer (score 0):

Посмею пованговать

Вероятно, у вас инпуты в форме имеют имена типа `name="addplan[name]"` или `addplan` это отдельный инпут, по которому код понимает, что нужно делать sql запрос. Однако, в условии вы указываете обычные не `_POST` переменные типа `$name, $description ...`, а ведь все данные, присылаемые формой, хранятся в постоянном массиве в зависимости от метода отправки данных, в данном случае в массиве $_POST

```
if (empty($name) || empty($description) || empty($price) || empty($mbt) || empty($conc) || empty($length) || empty($unit) || empty($vip)){
```

Вот эти переменные Вам нужно либо явно указать до проверки, либо изменить само условие на

```
if (empty($_POST['name']) || ... || empty($_POST['vip'])){
```

Либо на (зависит от того, как называются ваши инпуты

```
if (empty($_POST['addplan']['name']) || ... || empty($_POST['addplan']['vip'])){
```

Если Вы приведете пример html кода формы, то все встанет на свои места

Comment: У меня еще вопрос мне выдаёт ошибку в консоли насчёт Uncaught TypeError: $.drop is not a function
    at jquery.dashboard.js:1198
    at jquery.dashboard.js:1200 вот что у меня в этих строках     // FIXME required to use visual block builder
    $.drop({multi: true});

}(jQuery, window, document));